# Ruby error: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array of microposts named @microposts

so Its

```
@microposts=Micropost.all
@purchases=@microposts.select(:kind => "purchase")
```

and then it gives me the error

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)
    from (irb):23:in `select'
    from (irb):23
```

I am not sure if select is what I need. I was trying where but that didn't work either. I also tried @purchases=@microposts.select(kind:"sale") just in case but that didn't work either.

If its not clear, kind is a column in the microposts table that indicates either "sale" or "purchase". I want @purchases to be the array of microposts that is the "purchase" kind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you are using select in wrong way. You should use select before all
try it like this

```
@purchases = Micropost.where(:kind => "purchase")
```

this will do another query to db. If you don't want this and try using the @microposts list object, you can do this

```
@microposts=Micropost.all
@purchases=@microposts.collect{ |m| m if m.kind == "purchase"}.compact
```

where I suppose kind is the attribute of micropost object.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you're using it right either (for his problem, anyway) :)

Comment: I think that is working but I can't get @purchases to output so that I can check. Can you tell me how?

Comment: have you tried it in your console, just type rails c in project folder to start console and check it there.

Comment: yeah when I run it in the console (when I assign @purchases=@microposts.collect{ |m| if m.kind == "purchase"}.flatten) it doesn't give an error but it doesn't output anything. Does that mean it worked? If I try that line in the application, it gives me a syntax error saying expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'at the .flatten part

Comment: have you got any row with kind="purchase" in microposts table. if not u'll get nulll. Also please show me console screenshot, once, what is done there, if you can.

Comment: also check the new edit, by mistake i put it flatten. Flatten will keep all nils, but compact remove all nils and keep the objects which satify ur requirement.

Comment: ok compact worked thank you. The console output is correct. I am still having trouble getting them to show up in the view. Maybe you can help me out with that (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520635/ror-how-can-i-get-my-microposts-to-show-up)

Answer (score 0):

`.where` returns a criteria, not an array. This is what probably confused you. Try this.

```
arr = Micropost.where(:kind => 'purchase').to_a
```

Comment: would that work after the microposts have already been made? or would it update the array each time a micropost was made? can I name an array @purchases? if so would it be .to_@purchases. And what would I be assigning it to?

Comment: @BigBoy1337: every time you run this query, it will fetch recent data from the database. `#to_a` is a special method, it turns enumerable (which `.where` returns) to array. You can name your variable as you please.